# In concrete5, how can I get all a user's files?

Tags: php, concrete5

Using the built-in concrete5 file manager, how can I get a user's files (by the user's ID or otherwise)?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$user_id = 123;
$FileList = new FileList();
$FileList->filterByUserId($user_id);
```

Edit: I understand this question is very basic, but I posted it hoping to help others out because I did not see an answer on SO. If I've made any mistakes in my question, please let me know how I can improve.

Comment: Better read this article http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @smartrahat I made some improvements based on the article. I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `\Concrete\Core\File\FileList` class:

```php
<?php
$user_id = 111;

$list = new \Concrete\Core\File\FileList();
$list->filterByAuthorUserID($user_id);

$files = $list->executeGetResults();
```